# Angular routing without zone.js

Tags: angular, zone

I know that in new angular 9 we can work without zone.js because of the new engine Ivy. So I've created a new app and added one simple route /dashboard. And when I navigate to that route it seems that ngOnInit doesn't trigger. As a workaround I can do `this.router.navigate(['dashboard']).then(() => markDirty(this));`, but what to do when you manually open the /dashboard route from the address bar? Do I have to subscribe to all router events and trigger change detection manually? In angular 8 it doesn't work neither. I assume that all of this async stuff is handled by zonejs, so how to deal with it without zonejs? I'm dealing with hybrid app and zonejs does really affect to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you missing `<base>` tag in index.html. Add `<base href="/eapp">` to `<head>` tag to resolve

Answer (score 0):

The `Router` internally calls the `ɵmarkDirty(this)` method but this will not trigger a change detection cycle in a zoneless configuration. Instead, call the `ɵdetectChanges(this)` method on the `(activate)` event of the `RouterOutlet`:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[appActivateRoute]"
})
export class ActiveRoute {
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  @HostListener('activate')
  private activate() {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<router-outlet appActivateRoute></router-outlet>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```